# Setting Referenced Fields to null with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema thus:

```
var talentSchema=new Schema({
    name: String,
    active: Boolean,
    txfreq: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'frequency', null:true}
});
```

Not all the documents have a populated txfreq field and they are stored initially as null.

During operation of the app it is necessary to set some values of txfreq to null.

```
var pTalent=goose.talent 
    .where({txfreq:data.freqid,$isolated:1}) 
    .setOptions({multi:1}) 
    .update({txfreq:null}) 
    .lean() 
    .exec();
```

I am using a promise chain to ensure all the updates occur in the correct order, however setting of txfreq to null in this manner simply does not work.

With mongoose debugging set to true, no query is logged and the only way I can get any records set to null is to "find" the records with a cursor and set them to null individually before saving each document again.

I would very much like to do this with a single update command.

How can this be done?

It's almost as if mongoose is simply ignoring the command.

Comment: Why that weird API? Just use `Model.update()` with options "multi" set to true! http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update

Comment: To give some context, there is a sequence of updates that has to happen in the right order. The way I am achieving this is (attempting) to use the promise API's and am chaining a sequence of updates. This (I believe) requires me to use the .exec() function to return a promise. Otherwise my updates end up getting fulfilled in an uncontrollable order and this won't work.

Comment: All of Mongoose APIs (in version 4, at least) return promises. Just use Model.update() and don't pass a callback as last argument, but chain it with an exec: `var promise = Model.update(...).exec()`

Comment: PS if you have a sequence of operations, you may also want to give co (https://github.com/tj/co) a try to avoid the callback hell